# php - reset/clear an object?

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is use a temporary object to store values and then reset it back to empty without having to uset($tmpObject); ?

Here is some example code:

```
class Object {
    function ResetObject(){
        // code to remove all variables in an object here?
    }
}

$tmpObject = new Object();

foreach ($myArray as $arr){
    $tmpObject->val1 = "string1";
    $tmpObject->val2 = "string2";
    $tmpObject->val3 = "string3";
    $tmpObject->val4 = "string4";       
    $template->set('tmpObject',$tmpObject);
    $tmpObject->ResetObject();
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
class Object {
    function ResetObject() {
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->$key);
        }
    }
}
```

See: [Object iteration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Comment: that's actually flawed, you have to use `foreach ($this as $key=>$property) {unset($this->$key);}`

Comment: I edited your answer, add some function to mimic the object. We might have some property that is setup at `__construct` and didn't want to lose it.

Comment: Unsetting a property is not the same as setting it to null. Properties are null by default, so it would be better to set them to null. For more details and code, see my answer below.

Comment: Small note to using this in combination with abstract class and child classes. When calling a reset function within the abstract class with the goal to reset the properties of the child class, the class extending the abstract; the properties of the child class must be at least protected. Otherwise the reset function will not see the properties and won't reset them.

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer has a minor flaw which is that *unsetting* a property actually completely removes it from that object, so that a check like `$this->someProperty == null` would trigger an "Undefined property" notice. Properties are null by default, so this would be more correct:

```
class Object {
    function resetObject() {
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = null;  //set to null instead of unsetting
        }
    }
}
```

There's also the possibility that some of the properties could have been given default values (e.g. `protected $someArray = array();`)...if you want to reset all the properties back to their original default values then you have to use reflection:

```
class Object {
    function resetObject() {
        $blankInstance = new static; //requires PHP 5.3+  for older versions you could do $blankInstance = new get_class($this);
        $reflBlankInstance = new \ReflectionClass($blankInstance);
        foreach ($reflBlankInstance->getProperties() as $prop) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);
            $this->{$prop->name} = $prop->getValue($blankInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

That may be overkill but could be important in some scenarios. Note that this would fail if the class had required constructor arguments; in that case you could use [ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) (introduced in PHP 5.4), then call `__construct()` manually after calling `resetObject()`.

Comment: I think your reflection method might actually work with classes that implement` IteratorAggregate` and apply that method to a single array property of the class. For those classes, looping through `foreach($this)` would loop you through only one property. Whereas it seems like reflection will loop through all properties. But what about static properties of the class?

Comment: I think of resetting static properties as a totally different goal from what was described in the question. There's only one copy of each static property - no instances involved - so I'm not sure what the motivation would be to reset static properties.

Comment: I must have been low on sleep, of course you're right about static properties.

Comment: Small note to using this in combination with abstract class and child classes. When calling a reset function within the abstract class with the goal to reset the properties of the child class, the class extending the abstract; the properties of the child class must be at least protected. Otherwise the reset function will not see the properties and won't reset them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with static properties well. We won't like to change static properties.

Answer (score 3):

If your class has a constructor method which initialises everything, then you could just call that again to reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
function reset() {
    foreach (get_class_vars(get_class($this)) as $var => $def_val){
        $this->$var= $def_val;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does this unset (or set to null) variables not retrieved by `get_class_vars(...)`? The op does not want variable set to default values, op wants them unset?

Comment: I would suggest you add a little explanation to your answers, so that others can understand what you've done better.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of unset and even setting null, setting to default may be a better idea

```
class Foo {
public $bar = 'default bar';
private $baz = 'something';

  function __construct ()
  {
   /* assign whatever */
  }

 public function resetMe():Foo
 {
   $instance = new Foo();
   foreach($instance as $k => $v)
      $this->{$k} = $v;
 }
 return $this;
}
```

To use this

```
$foo = new Foo(); 
$foo->bar = 'set something different';
echo $foo->bar; // 'set something different'
$foo->resetMe();
echo $foo->bar; // 'default bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinitializing the variable will restore all object members to their preset values.

```
<?php

class Object {
  public $val1 = "val1";
  public $val2 = "val2";
}

$tmpObject = new Object();

$tmpObject->val1 = "string1";
$tmpObject->val2 = "string2";
$tmpObject->val3 = "string3";
$tmpObject->val4 = "string4";

var_dump($tmpObject);
$tmpObject = new Object();
var_dump($tmpObject);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
object(Object)#1 (4) {
  ["val1"]=>
  string(7) "string1"
  ["val2"]=>
  string(7) "string2"
  ["val3"]=>
  string(7) "string3"
  ["val4"]=>
  string(7) "string4"
}
object(Object)#2 (2) {
  ["val1"]=>
  string(4) "val1"
  ["val2"]=>
  string(4) "val2"
}
```

Comment: He want to have function to reset the object property. This usually use for model in MVC

Answer (score 0):

Another way which combine unset and set with default value.

```
class Object {
    public function resetObject()
    {
        $clean = new self;
        foreach ($this as $key => $val){

            // If the attribute have a default value, use it 
            if (isset($clean->$key)){
                $this->$key = $clean->$key;
            }else{
                unset($this->$key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection:

```
    private function resetPropertiesToDefault()
    {
        $blankInstance = $this->newInstance();
        $reflBlankInstance = new \ReflectionClass($blankInstance);
        foreach ($reflBlankInstance->getProperties() as $prop) {

            if ($prop->isStatic()) {
                continue;
            }

            $prop->setAccessible(true);

            $this->{$prop->name} = $prop->getValue($blankInstance);
        }
    }
```